# How to check what they type of this return value is in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript code:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Enum1,
  Enum2,
  Enum3,
  Enum4,
};

type MyType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

function myFunc(x: number): MyEnum | MyType {
     return MyEnum.Enum4;
}

const y = myFunc(55);
```

Now I want to test if the value of `y` is a member of MyEnum or an object of type MyType. How can I do it? The expression `(y in MyEnum)` gives the following compiler error:

> TS2360: The left-hand side of an "in" expression must be a private identified or of type "any", "string", "number" or "symbol".

Comment: `"b" in y`? That would tell you it's probably `MyType` and not `MyEnum`. You might be able to do `typeof y` if that returns `number`, it's `MyEnum`; if it's `object`, it's `MyType`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClJkCMAaDLZAJgM2wgGYyjIAWAgXwG400AXOAB2FjgBVuvALxR0mTAEMAXFGQAjYACdWEqPNkBndkoCWIAOatGbAGZgQAY3a6A9iCgQ4AMQuWAFAA9ZC5QEpZeAooAB8+QR4xQgklYHYwJQdPKAAeKAA2AAYoAH4+CgA6CjooWRQoGShPPHVZACInTh46qEYKzXChYzZLe20oOChRJ1crdwBWcb9WXpB+gC8hxxc3d3Sp1jRZzVsAG2AC3dsDdybgW1MB6a2+vYOjk7OLqHnpoA

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer is:**
you cannot check if a value is a specific `enum` nor `type`.

This can be explained with how TypeScript (TS) gets transpiled to JavaScript (JS).
Your TS-Snippet results in following JS-Code:
(used `tsc snippet.ts`)

```js
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Enum1"] = 0] = "Enum1";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Enum2"] = 1] = "Enum2";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Enum3"] = 2] = "Enum3";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["Enum4"] = 3] = "Enum4";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
;
function myFunc(x) {
    return MyEnum.Enum4;
}
var y = myFunc(55);
```

As you can see, the `type` is completely missing, as it simply is irrelevant / not present in vanilla JS. Further the `enum` has been transpiled into a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), thus you cannot perform a JS `instanceof` operation.

So a possible Solution for the `MyType`-Check would be to create a `class` instead of a Type. On the other Hand, there is no reasonable solution for the enum checking problematic, exept to simply not return two seperate types in your function.

Following some test-cases to illustrate the behaviour of `instanceof`:
(Also accessible on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-c5zytb?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts))

```
enum MyEnum {
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3,
    Enum4,
}

type MyType = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
};

class MyClass {
    constructor(public a: number) {
    }
}

describe('instanceof', () => {
    it('should be true on class instance', () => {
        const myClass = new MyClass(1);
        expect(myClass instanceof MyClass).toEqual(true);
    });

    it('should throw on comparison with enum', () => {
        const myEnum = MyEnum.Enum1;

        expect(() =>
            // @ts-ignore
            expect(myEnum instanceof MyEnum).toEqual(true)
        ).toThrow(TypeError);
    });

    it('should throw on comparison with type', () => {
        const myType: MyType = {a: 1, b: 'c'};
        expect(() =>
            // @ts-ignore
            expect(myType instanceof MyType).toEqual(false)
        ).toThrow(ReferenceError);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did that answer help you with your problem?